# Can you transcribe this mathematica expression into a formula or pseudocode?

Tags: evaluation

I want to understand the mathematca formula [A282720](https://oeis.org/A282720)

The description says

```
Number of nonzero terms in first n rows of the base-2 generalized Pascal triangle P_2
```

(But the [Pascal Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) has only nonzero terms, so the description makes nonsense).

His purpose is to generate the series:

```
0, 1, 3, 6, 9, 13, 18, 23, 27, 32, 39, 47, 54, 61, 69, 76, 81, 87, 96, 107, 117, 128, 141, 153, 162, 171, 183, 196, 207, 217, 228, 237, 243, 250, 261, 275, 288, 303, 321, 338, 351, 365, 384, 405, 423, 440, 459, 475, 486, 497, 513, 532, 549, 567
```

The Mathematica formula (on the same link) is:

```
Accumulate@ Prepend[Array[Sum[Mod[Binomial[# + k - 1, 2 k], 2], {k, 0, #}] &, 53], 0]
```

I'm not a Mathematica programmer, and don't understand what the formula means.

Can you translate it as an equation, or pseudocode?

I think that I understand the functions

```
Sum[Mod[Binomial
```

But I don't know what the `#` and `&` symbols means

Also `Prepend[Array` doesn't makes sense to me

`Accumulate@` I guess, means that the result is series that is a progressive accumulation of terms

Comment: The # and & symbols define an anonymous function where # is a slot for an argument. For example (# + 1 &) defines a function that adds one to its argument. `# + 1 &[ 2 ]` or shorthand  `# + 1 &[2]` will both give 3. In your case the function is `Sum[Mod[Binomial[# + k - 1, 2 k], 2], {k, 0, #}] &` and it's applied by `Array`  to numbers 1 through 53.

Comment: You could also do this in a more long-winded way. First define `f[n_]:=Sum[Mod[Binomial[n + k - 1, 2 k], 2], {k, 0, n}]`, then you have `Accumulate@ Prepend[Array[f, 53], 0]` which returns the list: `{0, f[1], f[1]+f[2], f[1]+f[2]+f[3], ..., (f[1]+f[2]+...+f[n])}`

Comment: `Array[f,n]` will return `{f[1] ,f[2], f[3], ..., f[n]}` and the `Prepend` just sticks a zero at the front of the list.

Comment: Note that this sequence sums the binary digits of the numbers in Pascal's triangle. So, 2 contributes 1 to the total

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sum[Mod[Binomial[# + k - 1, 2 k], 2], {k, 0, #}] &
```

`&` indicates that this is a function. `#` is the argument of the function. I transcribed it into mathematical notation for you, using $n$ instead of `#`.

$$
f(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n \left[ \binom{n+k-1}{2k} \bmod 2 \right]
$$

```
Array[..., 53]
```

This basically creates the sequence of numbers
$$
\bigl( f(1), f(2), \dots, f(53) \bigr)
$$

```
Prepend[..., 0]
```

prepends a 0 to the sequence, so now we have
$$
\bigl(0, f(1), f(2), \dots, f(53) \bigr)
$$

For the sake of simplicity, from here on I'll assume $f(0) = 0$, even though that is not consistent with the formula.

`Accumulate` computes partial sums, so the final result is
$$
g(n) = \sum_{i=0}^n f(i)
$$

---

We can convert the above back to Mathematica code that follows the formulas more closely:

```
f[n_] := Sum[Mod[Binomial[n + k - 1, 2 k], 2], {k, 0, n}]
f[0]  := 0

Accumulate[ Table[f[n], {n, 0, 53}] ]
```